# How to debug periodic performance issue

Tags: plugins, php, performance, server

I have an periodic performance issue on my site.
Seems like every exactly 10 secods, something clogs the CPU up to 100%.
[image]

I can clearly see it's something from the site itself rather than the environment because the processes that cause it are the php-cgi.exe processes.

How can I debug the issue and find out what is being called? And from there ofcourse find the addon ?
Is there somewhere when i can find a list of scheduled tasks that i could see (maybe find all tasks that are schedueled for every 10 seconds)?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
for server analysis of requests scheduled every 10 seconds to provide suggestions.